# Velocity Template : Display from nth position of an array

Tags: arrays, get, velocity, appdynamics

For customizing app dynamics email templates, we have to use velocity template 1.7

I have a health rule named ab-cd-ef-gh. First two part is constant and the last two part is the name of the microservice. I want to display the part after 'ef'. Please note that the length of the health rule is not fixed, meaning the part starting from 'ef' can have 2 part or 3 part or 5 part depending on the name.

I have used split function to split based on the delimiter '-'.

## set ($output=$originalmessage.split('-'))

Output variable has all the parts of the health rule.

Now I want to print from 2nd index of the array, ie from 'ef' till the end of the array. To get the size of the array , i used #set ($outputsize=$output.size()), ie is array.size().

How will print the part starting from 'ef' till the end of the array.

The logic I used was as below.

```
#set ($start=5)
#foreach ($i in [$start..$outputsize])
${arrays.asList($output).get($i)}
```

But, I am not getting the output. Please help me to get the service name printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VTL, arrays and lists are equivalent. On both of them you can use `.get(i)` or `[i]` to access the ith element, or call the `.size()` method.

So I guess that

```
#set ($outputsize = $output.size() - 1)
#set ($start=5)
#foreach ($i in [$start..$outputsize])
  $output.get($i)
#end
```

is enough, as would:

```
#set ($outputsize = $output.size() - 1)
#set ($start=5)
#foreach ($i in [$start..$outputsize])
  $output[$i]
#end
```

Comment: This works. Thanks Claude. I missed to give the output.size() - 1. I was trying with output.size().